# MATLAB is giving me a wrong multiplication answer

Tags: matlab, vector

I'm trying to solve equations on Matlab but when I multiply small numbers it gives me the wrong answer

the equation is

```
link31=10^-3*[5.57119434 537.12980876 315.00];
link32=10^-3*[111.77337538 311.006435 276.05400828];
link3=link31-link32

M3=link31

ux31=((link31(1) - link32(1)))^2
ux32=((link31(2) - link32(2)))^2
ux33=((link31(3) - link32(3)))^2

u3 = link3./sqrt(ux31 + ux32 + ux33)

M3(1)=(u3(2)*link3(3)-u3(3)*link3(2))
M3(2)=-1*(u3(1)*link3(3)-u3(3)*link3(1))
M3(3)=(u3(1)*link3(2)-u3(2)*link3(1))
```

which makes

```
u3(2) = 0.8943
link3(3) = 0.0389
u3(3) = 0.1540
link3(2) = 0.2261
```

so M3(1)=(u3(2)*link3(3)-u3(3)*link3(2)) should be equal to -3.1130e-05 but MATLAB is making it equal to 6.9389e-18

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with MATLAB GUI development or deployment of MATLAB executables. Please choose your tags more carefully.

Comment: `u3(2)*link3(3)-u3(3)*link3(2) == 0.034831-0.034831` How did you arrive at -3.1130e-05?

Comment: because 0.8943*0.0389-0.1540*0.2261 =-3.1130e-05 @beaker

Comment: You're cutting off precision. u3(2) is not 0.8943. It's 0.89433800271601471. Try setting `format long` and looking at the variables again.

Comment: does the format long affects this warning : Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND =
1.073998e-18.

Comment: No. `format long` does not change the underlying numbers, it just presents *more* of them rather than rounding to 4 significant digits.

Comment: okay, thank you..... but do you know the solution to this warning? it happens on multiplying an inv() of matrix by another matrix

Comment: The warning means you have an ill-formed problem. I.e., solving a linear system when you don't have enough independent equations. You need to examine your equation derivations to figure out why your setup is numerically singular.

Comment: thank you @JamesTursa